# Angular Material - How to create row on the child node of json

Tags: angular, input, angular-material, material-design

I am trying to create row on the child array in Angular Material. This seems quite simple if I do have no hierarchy of json. I am trying to show the images in material table where I want to have four column in which I want to show the name and type of cake in first column and image in second column and description in third column and fourth column will be for commenting purpose where user can comment on the item. Here is my json:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "0001",
    "type": "donut",
    "name": "Cake",
    "width": 200,
    "height": 200,
    "image": [
        {
            "url": "images/0001.jpg",
            "description": "Black Forest Gateau"
        },
        {
            "url": "images/0002.jpg",
            "description": "Eggless Truffle Cake"
        },
        {
            "url": "images/0003.jpg",
            "description": "Mango Meringue Cake"
        },
        {
            "url": "images/0004.jpg",
            "description": "Oreo Cheesecake"
        }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "0002",
    "type": "cookie",
    "name": "sugar cookie",
    "width": 200,
    "height": 200,
    "image": [
        {
            "url": "images/0001.jpg",
            "description": "Chocolate Chip Cookies"
        },
        {
            "url": "images/0002.jpg",
            "description": "Chocolate Cookies."
        },
        {
            "url": "images/0003.jpg",
            "description": "Oatmeal Chocolate Chip Cookies"
        },
        {
            "url": "images/0004.jpg",
            "description": "Peanut Butter Cookies"
        }
    ]
  }
]
```

in which I am defining table row like this

```html
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort aria-label="Elements">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="Detail">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Details </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let data">
      <strong>{{data.type}} </strong>&nbsp;
      <span>{{data.name}}</span>
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="Image">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Image </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let data">
      <div *ngFor="let image of data.image">
        <img height="data.height" width="data.width" src="image.url" alt="image.description" />
      </div>
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="Description">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Description </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let data">
      <div *ngFor="let image of data.image">
         {{image.description}}
      </div>
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="Comment">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Comment </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let data">
      <div *ngFor="let image of data.image">
        <div layout-gt-sm="row">
          <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
            <input matInput placeholder="Comment on your favorite food " value="">
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
      </div>
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>
```

This code snippet is creating a row on parent node of json whereas I want the row to be created on child row.

What am I doing wrong? It seems that I need to define in `*matRowDef` but I am unable to do so. I have tried `let row of data.image`. Is there a solution for creating a row on a child's node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example "Table with expandable rows":

https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples